# How to answer a question?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, grammar-choice, syntax

*Respondere* looks like a good verb for answering, but how can I say "to answer a question"?
I failed to find an answer by looking at dictionaries.
These options come to mind:

1. *quaestionem respondere*
2. *in quaestionem respondere*
3. *ad quaestionem respondere*
4. *quaestioni respondere*

Which one should I use?
Or should I use some other construction?
Does the choice depend on which word I use for "question" (*quaestio, rogatio, rogatum* or something else)?

Comment: I always thought of *quaestio* as a false friend... it's more like an "investigation" than a "question." I think a Roman would be somewhat surprised if you referred to "what do you want to eat for breakfast?" as a *quaestio*.

Comment: @brianpck, I agree; the Latin *quaestio* has a much broader meaning than the English "question". I think the English one is contained in the Latin one, but *quaestio* is probably not the best translation of "question". The choice of a question word shouldn't matter for the syntax required by *respondere*, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like @TomCotton's suggestion, but I thought I would add to it by providing some other options in Smith's *Copious and Critical English-Latin Dictionary*.

I think, first of all, that *quaestio* is not a good translation of English *question*. If you look through the [Lewis & Short entry for *quaestio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquaestio), the word has a technical legal meaning and is also used to refer to something closer to the English word *investigation*. The Scholastics would refer to different topics of investigation, such as *Utrum Deus Sit*, as a *quaestio*, but I do not think they would regard *Quid tibi nomen est?* as one.

That said, Smith recommends **rogatum** or **interrogatum** as a more direct translation.

*To answer a question* would thus be **ad rogatum respondere**, which has good classical precedent:

Cicero uses this construction to refer to rhetorical questions in his *Orator*:

> sic igitur dicet ille, quem expetimus, ut...interrogando urgeat; ut rursus quasi ad interrogata sibi ipse respondeat. (Cic. *Or* 40)

Other examples substitute *rogatum* with another word:

> ad ea, quae quaesita erant, respondebat. (Cic. *Phil.* 1.1)

The *ad* appears to be unnecessary, at least in colloquial speech. Here is Plautus:

> hoc quod te rogo responde mihi. (Pl. *Merc.* 1.101)

and Terence:

> etiam tu hoc respondes? (Ter. *Andr.* 2.2.8)

Comment: Many thanks! Perhaps the quote from Plautus could be read as an internal object (like "hoc respondeo") which often replaces other syntax with a plain accusative.

Comment: A technical note: @-pings don't work in answers. It's not against any rule, of course, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, actually I'm not familiar with what you mean by "internal object." What's an example?

Comment: The construction has many names, including "cognate accusative". [Here](http://www.hhhh.org/perseant/libellus/aides/allgre/allgre.390.html) are several examples. Simple examples: *id laetor*, *hoc assentior*, *pugnam pugnare*, *vitam vivere*. The object is typically a pronoun or a noun related to the verb.

Answer (score 8):

You could use *responsum dare*, which answers pretty well in every case that I can think of, no matter what the precise choice of word for *question*. Both the person addressed and the question itself can be either dative, or ad + accusative; Wm. Smith's dictionaries have plenty of examples.. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! *Responsum dare* is indeed a good idea. Do you think it's the only option, or could *respondere* work as well?