# What is on or off topic?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, modern-life

When defining the scope of a site like this one, we need to decide what is on topic and what is off topic.
How can I discuss such things in Latin?
It can be a pair of adjectives or some other construction to make the distinction.
The best option that comes to mind is *situi aptus/ineptus*, but I wouldn't be surprised if there is something better.

Comment: Why not use the feminine, as in _rogatio_ apta?

Comment: @Rafael The adjective *aptus/ineptus* with a [question word](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1320/79) sounds like a good idea. Can you give that suggestion as an answer?

Comment: I'm still hesitant about _aptus_. It is good, but I wonder if there is something better. Would a Roman understand what we mean by _ad hoc_?

Comment: @Rafael I think using *ad hoc* in this meaning would be a little... *ad hoc*. I don't think a Roman would understand it in its modern (English) meaning. It could work with some other words to support it. I'm hesitant about *aptus* too, and that's why I asked. Perhaps *gratus* would work?

Comment: I decided to collect the suggestions from the comments into a CW answer. Feel free to edit it if something new comes to your mind.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ideas (mainly adjectives to go with *rogatum* or some such word) that have been proposed so far in comments and the question itself.
Feel free to add any new ideas here.

- *situi aptus/ineptus*
- *ad hoc*
- *gratus*
- *pertinens*
- *decens*
- *decet*
- *adhibere/prohibere* and *adhibitus/prohibitus*

**This list contains no explanation or justification, just possibly useful ideas. If you want to elaborate on one or more idea, please write it up in a separate answer!**
This answer is community wiki so that anyone can edit to add a suggestion but no one gets reputation for the votes.

Answer (score 2):

One of the pleasures of this site is the civility shown to those who enquire and to those who reply. In keeping with this nonjudgmental ethos I would therefore suggest:

***nitēns,*** (present participle of *niteō*) brilliant, shining --to show approbation, on-topic

***nītēns*** (present participle of deponent *nītor*) on one's knees, striving, making an effort --for off-topic.

Provided that it was not said out loud, or marked with a macron, the only giveaway, I suppose, would be the Accusative/Ablative *situm/sitū.*

Comment: This is a fun one! It's a little difficult to make the distinction between *nĭtens* and *nītens* in writing, but not impossible.

Comment: This is the best thing

Comment: I was going to post a finger-wagging about how far-fetched the "off-topic" meaning was, but then I saw [meaning I.B.3 of *nitor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnitor1) and lost all composure :)

Comment: I added macrons to show that the two are indeed marginally distinct; feel free to roll back if you don't like them.

Comment: @brianpck To help (?) you get your composure back together, I decided to ask [a question about the meaning I.B.3 of *niiti*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4931/79).

Answer (score 2):

My submission is ***[situi]*** [***consentaneus***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconsentaneus):

> agreeing or according with something, suited to, becoming, meet, fit, proper

The formulaic phrase *consentaneum est*, in this context, would mean "That is on-topic," based on its L&S meanings:

> it agrees with something, it is according to reason, fitting, consistent, proper

Off-topic could be *non/haud consentaneus* or even, as attested in later Latin, *[situi]* [*inconsentaneus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dinconsentaneus).